# Abrir ventana con opciones ratón encima de link

Tags: php, html, enlace

Deseo tener una ventana que me muestre una opción en plan **desplegable** para poder acceder al **perfil** del **cliente**.

**Al pasar el ratón por encima del link**, usuario registrado, que se muestre un "cuadro/ventana/opciones" para poder hacer click en una opción para ir a "Datos del cliente".

**¿Cómo se llama a ese "cuadro/ventana/opciones? Para tener un ejemplo de cómo podría realizarse en HTML o DOM o Javascript o jQuery...**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Se los conoce como `dropdown`, `menu desplegable`, etc.

Comment: ¿Algún ejemplo? ¿Se pueden programar en los lenguajes que dije anteriormente?

Comment: Si necesitas ejemplos, busca en Google. Aquí solo brindamos ayuda a problemas concretos. Te recomiendo leer [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: De acuerdo, si tienes privilegios borra la pregunta. Tienes razón, es que no me salía el nombre de "dropdown" lo cual buscaba.

Answer (score 3):

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo funcional con lo que deseas.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="menu1" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Usuario@usuario
    <span class="caret"></span></a>
    
     <buttom class="btn btn-info dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Salir
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out "></span></buttom>
    
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Perfil</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Fotos</a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">Salir</a></li>  
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```